# I am trying to set up a search query for a company directory

Tags: search, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019, kql

As title mentioned, I am trying to set up a company directory. Below is the KQL I'm trying use.

I want to exclude any account with server, admin, workstation, Events, things of that nature.

```
{searchboxquery} contentclass=spspeople  -FirstName:SP_ -PreferredName:SharePoin-PreferredName:Workstation -LastName:NonElevatedWorkstation -LastName:Domain -PreferredName:Elevated -PreferredName<>Admin -PreferredName<>server  {SearchBoxQuery}
```